# Apply SVG mask on hover

Tags: javascript, html, svg, mouseevent

I am trying to apply a svg mask when the cursor enters a svg circle. The masking is working correctly but the events are not fired.

How can I properly set event listeners to svg elements so that when the circle contained in `<svg id="container">` is hovered, mask is applied to `<rect id="masked">`?

```js
const svg = document.getElementById('container')

svg.addEventListener('onmouseover', (e) => {
  console.log('hover')

  const masked = document.getElementById('masked')
  masked.setAttribute('fill', 'grey')
  masked.setAttribute('fill-opacity', '70%')
  masked.setAttribute('mask', 'url(#myMask)')
})

svg.addEventListener('onmouseleave', (e) => {
  console.log('leave')

  const masked = document.getElementById('masked')
  masked.setAttribute('fill', 'none')
  masked.setAttribute('fill-opacity', '100%')
  masked.removeAttribute('mask')
})
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

svg,
circle {
  pointer-events: all;
}
```

```html
<svg id="mySVG" width="600" height="250">
  <mask id="myMask" x="0" y="0" width="600" height="250">
    <rect width="400" height="250" fill="white" />
    <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="25" fill="black" />
  </mask>
  <rect id="masked" x="0" y="0" width="600" height="250" fill="grey"></rect>
  <!-- The following svg element is supposed to trigger events -->
  <svg id="container">
    <!-- This circle overlaps the circle in <mask> -->
    <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="25" fill="none" stroke="black" />
  </svg>
</svg>
```

Comment: The events are called `mouseover` and `mouseleave`, if you reference them in `addEventListener(event, callback)`. `onmouseover` is the name of the **attribute** you would write in markup: `<svg onmouseover="callback()" >`.

Comment: What a silly mistake... Your suggested change works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The events are called `mouseover` and `mouseleave`, not `onmouseover` and `onmouseleave`.

```js
const svg = document.getElementById('container')

svg.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
  console.log('hover')

  const masked = document.getElementById('masked')
  masked.setAttribute('fill', 'grey')
  masked.setAttribute('fill-opacity', '70%')
  masked.setAttribute('mask', 'url(#myMask)')
})

svg.addEventListener('mouseleave', (e) => {
  console.log('leave')

  const masked = document.getElementById('masked')
  masked.setAttribute('fill', 'none')
  masked.setAttribute('fill-opacity', '100%')
  masked.removeAttribute('mask')
})
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

svg,
circle {
  pointer-events: all;
}
```

```html
<svg id="mySVG" width="600" height="250">
  <mask id="myMask" x="0" y="0" width="600" height="250">
    <rect width="400" height="250" fill="white" />
    <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="25" fill="black" />
  </mask>
  <rect id="masked" x="0" y="0" width="600" height="250" fill="grey"></rect>
  <!-- The following svg element is supposed to trigger events -->
  <svg id="container">
    <!-- This circle overlaps the circle in <mask> -->
    <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="25" fill="none" stroke="black" />
  </svg>
</svg>
```